# Why does 0.49999999999999998 get rounded to 1,?

Tags: python, rounding

Why does round in the following code:

```
>>> round(0.49999999999999997)
0.0
>>> round(0.49999999999999998)
1.0
>>> round(1.4999999999999998)
1.0
>>> round(1.4999999999999999)
2.0
```

round `0.49999999999999998` and `1.4999999999999999` up instead of down, and why does this behavior happen for `0.49999999999999998` by one 9 after the decimal later than for `1.4999999999999998`?

Comment: Regarding the additional question of why it happens "one 9 later" for 1.4999...: floating-point numbers have a fixed number of *significant* digits.  You can think of the integral part "1." already consuming one significant digit, so there's one less digit left for the fractional part.

Comment: Use `decimal.Decimal` for infinite precision floating point numbers.